# Mobile application testing

Tags: selenium, mobile, android, ios, appium

I am new to "Mobile application testing" and I googled and got appium and selandroid.

I want to learn mobile application testing and I have experience selenium webdriver with java.

**Queries are:**

1. I am not sure to learn Mobile application testing do I require IOS, android mobile phones?. (I have IOS Mobile apple 3gs).
2. If real mobile is not required then, how to do this test any links, suggestions, etc.
3. Open source tool to learn Mobile application testing and tutorial.

**Please suggest.....!!!!!**

Thanks much..

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad, therefore the answer has to be broad as well. "mobile application testing" is as specific as "mobile application development".

1. Applications are tested at different layers. One extremely important layer is [exploratory testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing), which requires that the tester runs the application in a setup that's as close as possible to that of a real user, and uses the application in any way they can think of. Given the cost of a tester ($$$) versus the cost of a handset ($), this means testing requires a lot of different mobile phones and tablets. These are usually owned by the company, not the tester.
2. Run the mobile OS in a virtual environment. The specifics depend highly on the OS, OS version, and application development framework. A lot of the options can be found by googling the name of the OS/framework, combined with "automated test". E.g "[iOS automated test](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20automated%20test)" or "[xamarin automated test](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin%20automated%20test)".
3. Too broad a question, and too opinion based to provide an objective answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more context in order to get useful answers, what would you expect from a question about "testing stationary applications" ?

A mobile application is...an application and you test it as such in the context of the environment which happens to be mobile.

Yes there are some relevant tools, but like in the stationary case using them depends on your needs, environment and knowledge.

I would suggest starting small (or big, depends on your point of view)- learn to test first,  and yes an Iphone 3gs is as good as any other phone.

Choose an application and start testing it... if you want to do something meaningful try an open source app. Google "ios open source apps" and choose something like [WordPres for iOS](https://apps.wordpress.org/) (supports only iOS 7 that is not available for iPhone 3gs) and report real bugs

Comment: "WordPres for iOS" will support IOS 7 onwards, but iPhone 3gs will not support IOS 7. But can give alternate application sample.

Comment: Ya, I know but I have commented on your answer. He is talking about 3gs mobile not 4, 5 or 6 iPhone models.

Comment: removed my comment and edited the answer, thx